# is there a hidden meaning to それとなく?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I got bumped in the term それとなく in these two sentences

```
1. だから今はそれとなく散々淡々と暮らしていて
2. 思い出して魚の眼 Oh Oh! それとなくキルミーして！Oh Oh!
```

Jisho said `indirectly; obliquely`, but feels like it is not fit well to the translation. There is any nuance or other meaning to this?

disclaimer, these two lines are from the song `ガランド`. So probably they are not 100% understandable or grammatical correct. But any example that will help me understand this term better will be great :-)

Thanks, Or

Comment: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F